# How to check if items repeat in pandas column with multiple lists?

Tags: python, pandas, list, object

I have this pandas df:

```
                                               Name
0                      [MARCIO, HAMILTON, FERREIRA]
1                    [NILSON, MARTINIANO, FERREIRA]
2                         [WALTER, MALIENI, JUNIOR]
3                  [CARLOS, ALBERTO, ARAUJO, NETTO]
```

If one of the items appear in another list I want to tag it. In this case the output should be like this:

```
                                               Name       Check
0                      [MARCIO, HAMILTON, FERREIRA]        True
1                    [NILSON, MARTINIANO, FERREIRA]        True
2                         [WALTER, MALIENI, JUNIOR]       False
3                  [CARLOS, ALBERTO, ARAUJO, NETTO]       False
```

Is there a pythonic way to do that or I will need to apply a set of `for` sentences? (`for i in object: for k in list`...). Since my file is quite large I'm afraid it will be very heavy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to Ben's answer but using `duplicated` instead of `groupby().nunique()`:

```
s = series.explode().reset_index()
df['Check'] = (s.drop_duplicates()
                .duplicated('Name', keep=False)
                .groupby(s['index']).any()
              )
```

Output:

```
                               Name  Check
0      [MARCIO, HAMILTON, FERREIRA]   True
1    [NILSON, MARTINIANO, FERREIRA]   True
2         [WALTER, MALIENI, JUNIOR]  False
3  [CARLOS, ALBERTO, ARAUJO, NETTO]  False
```

Comment: It is a series object, so "Name" isn't a column in the start

Comment: Given that you want to end up with a dataframe there is no point to don't convert your series to_frame.

Comment: Sorry I missed that part. In which case, you may be better off dealing with the problem on the original data before the said groupby operation

Comment: I can turn it into a df, noprob. However even though I'm getting errors: df.explode() AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'explode'

Comment: `explode` is available from pandas `0.25+`.

Comment: would there be a solution on pandas 0.22?

Comment: Since `explode` is somewhat `ungroup`. you might be better solving this prior to groupby as mentioned earlier.

Comment: alright, I updated my pandas and turned it into a df. I will update the question, would you mind to put the answer applied to a df?

Answer (score 2):

We can do `explode` then do `transform` with `nunqiue` find the index `duplicated` with same value

```
s=df.Name.explode().reset_index()
v=(s.groupby('Name')['index'].transform('nunique')>1).groupby(s['index']).any()
Out[465]: 
index
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
Name: index, dtype: bool
df['Check']=v
```

Comment: It is a series object, so "Name" isn't exactly a column

Comment: I'm getting errors: series.explode() `NameError: name 'series' is not defined` or s.explode() `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'explode'`

Comment: I didn't have pandas 0.25, that was the prob as appointed by Quang Hoang. I updated my pandas and turned the object it into a df. I updated the question, would you mind to put the answer applied to a df?

Comment: @abutremutante I just roll back ~